# Is IoC appropriate for a computational engine?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

We are building a computational engine where we have a number of objects that interact in performing the computation. The objects have dependencies among themselves and mimic a subset of a real-world system. We are building the computational engine in a phased manner where we incrementally model parts of the system and hence could result in a change in the dependency graph as we progress. We could explicitly state the dependency between the objects in code but this may result in having to change that portion of code in future. Would using IoC alleviate this problem? Or would it be an overkill?

Comment: Can you provide some example code before and after one of these phases?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that applying dependency injection can be useful:

1. It allows you to abstract code that needs to be tested in isolation. In your case you might want to split the computational engine in multiple parts to make it easier to test the smaller parts of that engine, or abstract the database engine that the engine is using internally.
2. It allows that engine to be developed by multiple teams. By depending on the abstraction the other team provides (or you specified for the other team) it allows you to make progress, without being blocked by the progress of the other team.
3. If the engine consists of smaller parts that must be changable (specification pattern), injecting abstractions for those parts can help achieve this. You could even do this at runtime if you simply depend upon an abstraction.

If however, this computational engine is developed by one team, hasn't got any dependencies on anything that needs to be abstracted (database, file system, etc), and isn't that complex that testing the separate parts would make development and verification easier, using dependency injection in that computational engine might not help.